# Typechecking in function compositions

Tags: haskell

Why is not ghci throwing a type error when I do the following?

```
let d = tail . head
```

Should this not say that tail wants [a] while head gives it only a?

Comment: because the head of the list may be a list, too. If you check the type of `d`, you will see it is expected to be `[[a]] -> [a]`

Comment: @SassaNF That's an answer, why not post it as such?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the types were more specialized, like

```
head :: [Int] -> Int
tail :: [Int] -> [Int]
```

then tail.head would be ill typed indeed.
But as it stands, the types are

```
head :: [a] -> a
tail :: [b] -> [b]
```

I have used the type variables "a" and "b" so that you don't think they have to be the same.
In that case, having a = [b], the types become

```
head :: [[b]] -> [b]
tail :: [b] -> [b]
```

and they are composable.

Comment: AA I see, not the first time I miss to think about that :)